# Reading json from file and deserializing always returns null

Tags: c#, json, streamreader

I am reading Json from a file and when I try to deserialize it using Newtonsoft Json it returns null. I am constructing the JSON class from http://json2csharp.com/
. I am not sure of the reason why it says null is it because of the special symbols like \n,\r etc it introduces when using the StreamReader. Please help.

Json (I checked with JsonLint and its valid json)

```
{
    "Machine Learning Functions": [{
        "Function": "JaccardDistance",
        "ArgCount": 2,
        "Arg1": "Point1",
        "Arg1Type": "Point",
        "Arg2": "Point2",
        "Arg2Type": "Point",
        "Return": "distance",
        "ReturnType": "Double"
    }],
    "Math Functions": [{
        "Function": "Cosine",
        "ArgCount": 2,
        "Arg1": "document1",
        "Arg1Type": "String",
        "Arg2": "document2",
        "Arg2Type": "String",
        "Return": "angle",
        "ReturnType": "Integer"
    }, {
        "Function": "SQRT",
        "ArgCount": 1,
        "Arg1": "SomeNumber",
        "Arg1Type": "Integer",
        "Return": "Number",
        "ReturnType": "Integer"
    }]

}
```

C# code (taken from json2csharp)

```
 public class MachineLearningFunction
    {
        public string Function { get; set; }
        public int ArgCount { get; set; }
        public string Arg1 { get; set; }
        public string Arg1Type { get; set; }
        public string Arg2 { get; set; }
        public string Arg2Type { get; set; }
        public string Return { get; set; }
        public string ReturnType { get; set; }
    }

    public class MathFunction
    {
        public string Function { get; set; }
        public int ArgCount { get; set; }
        public string Arg1 { get; set; }
        public string Arg1Type { get; set; }
        public string Arg2 { get; set; }
        public string Arg2Type { get; set; }
        public string Return { get; set; }
        public string ReturnType { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<MachineLearningFunction> MachineLearningFunctions { get; set; }
        public List<MathFunction> MathFunctions { get; set; }
    }
```

This json is stored Into a file and I am reading as follows when I keep a break point it reads the string by introducing some special charecters like \n,\r etc. But when I try to deserialize the break point shows null and I get a null reference exception when iterating through the list.

```
 string json = string.Empty;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Nikh\OneDrive\Documents\Application/json.txt"))
            {
                json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
 ParseAndConstructJson(json);

public void ParseAndConstructJson(string json) //Using Newtonsoft json
        {
            RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
            foreach (var item in obj.MachineLearningFunctions)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(item.Function);
            }//DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define with `JsonProperty` your properties in the `RootObject` to map them to the json file.

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="Machine Learning Functions")]
    public List<MachineLearningFunction> MachineLearningFunctions { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="Math Functions")]
    public List<MathFunction> MathFunctions { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @nikhil you can mark the answer as correct if helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces from:
"Machine Learning Functions" and "Math Functions" in the JSON file and it will deserialize your object without any problems.